# How to centralize a custom toast creation

Tags: android, toast

in my application i use a custom toast in almost all the activity. To create the custom toast i have the following method :

```
private void getCustomToast(String message)
{
    LayoutInflater li   = getLayoutInflater();
    View toastlayout    = li.inflate(R.layout.toast_error, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));
    TextView text       = (TextView) toastlayout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
    text.setText(message);

    Toast toast = new Toast(this);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(toastlayout);
    toast.show();
}
```

It works fine but for each activity I need to duplicate this method, not really respectfull of the DRY principle ...

How can i make a static class (for example) in which i have a method which gonna fire the custom toast on the current activity ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just making the method to accept the activity, something like: private void getCustomToast(String message, Activity activity)

Comment: Never think about it, but i will give a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a custom abstract Activity that contains the toast method, and then extend that for your application's activities:

```
public abstract class ToastActivity extends Activity {

    protected void getCustomToast(String message)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        View toastlayout  = li.inflate(
                R.layout.toast_error, 
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));

        TextView text = (TextView) toastlayout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
        text.setText(message);

        Toast toast = new Toast(this);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(toastlayout);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to say you can create a [static] class which will accept a Context object. Then use:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

So in your static class:

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static void toast(Context context, String msg)
         {
              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.DURATION_LONG).show();

         }

}
```

Or something like that