# How to write a class in android extends Toast?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there anyway to to extend Toast in android.
for eg------

### public class CustomToast extends android.widget.Toast

how can i use the above class to display toast

Comment: post the relevant code

Comment: Are you trying to customise the functionality or the layout? You can change how a Toast looks like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686398/android-custom-toast-notification-inherit-default-toast

Comment: Search before posting

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why you need to extend Toast. I thought I needed to also but then I saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041475/how-to-centralize-a-custom-toast-creation